# registerPolicies function in laravel returns undefined method error

Tags: laravel-8

I am new to Laravel. I tried to implement policies in Laravel but I am getting this error:

> Call to undefined method App\Providers\AppServiceProvider::registerPolicies()

Anybody can help me how can I resolve it?

Answer (score 1):

Just Use these three things only!

```
use Laravel\Passport\Passport;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Gate;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\AuthServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;

class AuthServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
/**
 * The policy mappings for the application.
 *
 * @var array
 */
 protected $policies = [
    'App\Model' => 'App\Policies\ModelPolicy',
 ];

/**
 * Register any authentication / authorization services.
 *
 * @return void
 */
 public function boot()
 {
    $this->registerPolicies();

    Passport::routes();
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Whatever you created about policies in your file `AppServiceProvider` move it the `AuthServiceProvider`. The method `registerPolicies` is exclusive to `AuthServiceProvider` as you'll see when you open the extended class.